# STS cannot import existing file system into workspace

Tags: import, filesystems, directory, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I followed following steps.

1. Start STS (Starts with default project named "Servers" already created)
2. right click package explorer, click on import -> General -> File System
3. Select directory -> Click Select All

After this step, I should be able to import my directory into "workspace", instead STS "forces" me to import file system to existing project.

Also, if I try to create a folder into top level workspace, STS does not allow me to do that as well.

I need to be able to import the whole directory into the workspace not a project.

Answer (score 0):

You can only import filesystems into existing projects and you can only create folders in existing projects.  The top-level is only for projects.

What you need to do first is create a new project with an external location that is rooted at the filesystem you want to import.  The project will be created right there and automatically include all sub-folders.

Alternatively, if the root directory is already an eclipse project, do this:

```
File -> Import -> Existing projects into workspace -> Select root directory
```

This is a bit confusing that you can't import a bunch of files and folders as a project, but this is how Eclipse has worked since the dawn of time (I think time started in the year 2000).